# python read txt file missing data

Tags: python, csv, pandas

This is output from terminal 
8677
(8637, 2)
This is the code, don't know why some data is missing? The last 40 entries of img_list.txt can not be found in random_list.txt. What am I missing?

```
import os
import argparse
import math
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

example_dirname = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

caffe_dirname = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(example_dirname,'../..'))
training_dirname = os.path.join(caffe_dirname,'data/101')
img_dirname = os.path.join(caffe_dirname,'data/101/101_ObjectCategories')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser =  argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description = 'Arrage the 101 data set')
    parser.add_argument(
        'train_percent',type = float, default = 0,
        help= "the percent of the training data")
    args = parser.parse_args()


    img_num = 0
    class_lable = 0
    img_class = open('image_class.txt','w')
    img_list = open('img_list.txt','wb')
    # img_test = open('test.txt','w')
    dirs = os.listdir(img_dirname)
    for folder in dirs:
        name = os.path.join(img_dirname, folder)
        new_name = os.path.join(img_dirname, folder.lower())
        if new_name != name:
            os.rename(name,new_name)

    dirs.sort()
    for folder in dirs:
        img_class.write(folder + ' ' + str(class_lable) + os.linesep)
        temp = os.path.join(img_dirname,folder)
        for file in sorted(os.listdir(temp)):   
            # print file        
            img_list.write(os.path.join(temp,file)+' '+str(class_lable)+ os.linesep)
            img_num = img_num + 1
        class_lable = class_lable + 1


    print img_num

    img_train = math.floor(args.train_percent * img_num)
    df = pd.read_csv('img_list.txt',sep = " ",  header = None)
    print df.shape  

    # df.columns = ["img_path", "img_class"]
    #df = df.iloc[np.random.permutation(img_num)]
    df.to_csv("randomlist.txt", header=None, index=None, sep=' ', mode='w')

    # df1 = df.iloc[:img_train]
    # df2 = df.iloc[img_train:]
    #print df1

    img_class.close()
    img_list.close()
```

Comment: use `img_list.close()` before you start reading from `'img_list.txt'`. System may keep data in buffer and save it in file when you call `close()`, not when call `write()`

Comment: Thank you! It works. Do you mean if I don't close it, some data of img_list are still in buffer, so when I use read_csv I can not get it?

Comment: yes, some data still are in buffer and close() sends them to file.

Answer (score 0):

Use `img_list.close()` before you start reading from `'img_list.txt'`.

System may keep data in buffer and saves it in file when you call `close()`, not when you call `write()`. So it saves some data after you read file with `pandas`.